# CSS - how to show icons when you go over the div

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I just wanted to show the icons when you go over the div. I already have Opactiy in there but I don't know what to do next.

```
 .new-tasks .item-controls  {
        opacity: 0;
        .item-controls{
          &:hover {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
        }
```

```
<div class="content">
        <h2 class="head">School</h2>
        <div class="inout">
          <input
            id="storageTask"
            type="text"
            name="item"
            class="text"
            placeholder="Enter a new Tasks..."
          />
          <button class="enter">
            <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          <ul class="list-container"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
    let controlIcons = document.createElement("div");
    controlIcons.setAttribute("class", "item-controls")
    let spanDel = document.createElement("span");
    let spanDone = document.createElement("span");
    
    let done = document.createElement("done-button");
    let del = document.createElement("del-button");

    spanDel.appendChild(done);
    spanDone.appendChild(del);

    
    controlIcons.appendChild(spanDel);
    controlIcons.appendChild(spanDone);
    
    spanDel.setAttribute("class", "delete");
    spanDone.setAttribute("class", "finish");
```

Edit: I hope that can be helped. With display:block and display:none it doesn't work.

the icons are created in javascript in item-controls. And "new-task" is the new input. item-controls div is in a "list div"

Thx for helping my brothers

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please can you add more code so we can understand your question better. Are you able to show us the HTML used (including the HTML generated from the Javascript)?

Comment: can you show your all code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go for `display:none;` and `display:block;` when onhover

create a div in html set custom properties to it as you like(width etc.) with the icon from js.
Then add the css for normal and onhover state.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS can be updated as follows:

```
.item-controls{
   display: none;
}
.item-controls:hover{
   display: block (or whatever display you'd like)
}
```

The code above will hide the item controls element by default (with `display:none`) and show it on hover with the `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.show{ 
display: none;
}
.show-other:hover .show{
display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-other">HOVER ME
<div class="show">Everything!</div>

</div>
```

Comment: read my question correctly and do not write an answer that I have already tried because it was on some page. it. works. not.